# Assigning page results from scrape-it npm to a variable returns Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, npm, promise

I'm attempting to use scrape-it as a dependency that I downloaded from NPM earlier today. I'm able to get the content back that I want, but need to store the results in a variable rather than handle them via the callback.

Using the 'sample' from scrape-it docs, when I try the following:

```
var myVar = scrapeIt("http://ionicabizau.net", {
    title: ".header h1"
  , desc: ".header h2"
  , avatar: {
        selector: ".header img"
      , attr: "src"
    }
}).then(page => {
    return page;
});

console.log(myVar);
```

I get the result: Promise { <pending> }

I've also tried using 'await' prior to calling the scrapeIt() function, but when I do that locally 'Unexpected identifier' syntax error in return.

Mind you, when I've tried this on the RunKit + npm site, it does work there, but it doesn't work for me locally. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the package, and it seems like I have all the necessary dependencies, so not sure what I'm doing wrong. :-\

While this obviously does touch on the asynchronous nature of javascript, the focal point of the question is to better understand interaction with promises.

Comment: By "I've tried _this_" you mean the attempt using `await`, because otherwise `myVar` would be a promise as you said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You're trying to evaluate something waaaaay before you have got it.  `myVar` is a promise, so you should be doing your work with the results of the call in the `then` func.  You may think you should block the current function execution until you have the result, but you don't.  Simply split off the remaining logic and call it from within the `then` func.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to see that. I had hoped I could store the results in a variable someway, but no success. :-\ While try to work within the then function and see if I can pull off what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scrapeIt` method is asynchronous due to the async nature of the request module.

`scrapeIt.scrapeHTML` is sync, but it expects the HTML as a string.

So, as long you can get the HTML from somewhere, you can do something very similar to what you did:

```
var myVar = scrapeIt.scrapeHTML("<h1>Hello</h1>", {
    title: "h1"
});
console.log(myVar);
// { title: "h1" }
```

You can think of something async as something that *you have to wait for* (e.g. downloading the HTML of the page—that takes time). That's why there are callbacks and promises and so on.

```
scrapeIt("http://ionicabizau.net", {
    title: ".header h1"
  , desc: ".header h2"
  , avatar: {
        selector: ".header img"
      , attr: "src"
    }
}).then(myVar => {
   // Use myVar, only once it's ready
   // Once the page is downloaded and parsed
   // this function is triggered
   console.log(myVar)

   // Here you can do something with myVar
});

// At this point the page is not downloaded yet.
```

Comment: So other than perhaps pulling the body content from a page on my own and then using scrape-it to pull the info I'm looking for, is it possibly using the standard scrapeIt method and somehow store the results in a variable?

Comment: @ReubenV You *do* store the data in a variable using the `then` method. But you have to understand the async nature of the whole thing. Why do you want it to get immediately?

Comment: Ooooh... I see how it works now within the .then method. My apologies for being so dense on that. I should be able to work with it fine within .then now that I understand the flow, better.

My apologies as I'm still relatively new to Promises. Your edited explanation cleared it up for me!